Finding RθJA for 2N3055
The data sheet does not provide RθJA spec. So how does one go about calculating it?

Post the datasheet.

Why choose a power transistor for a situation where you aren't using it at power (or, most of its rating, anyway)? Also, why a particularly old type such as this?

There's no way to use a TO-3 package without some kind of heatsink, so specifying $\Theta_{JA}$ is rather pointless.

Well, not none, there have been some applications where the switching capacity was used, or in pulsed operation. You can mount a TO-3 on a PCB with standoffs instead of a heatsink. But those are very old applications indeed (for which there are better solutions now, too).

@DaveTweed I agree. Except that I wouldn't go so far as to say "no way." I've put them on bakelite perfboard and even drilled holes in the perfboard so I could screw them down. So they can be used without a heatsink. Just rarely. And then, only by idiots like me. ;)

@periblepsis: The point is, even adding just a screw, a nut and a lug for the electrical connection adds a significant amount of mass and surface area to the package, so any $\Theta_{JA}$ value specified by the manufacturer instantly becomes worthless.

\$R_{θJA}\$ is measured for a specific test setup, I don't know that you can calculate it as factors other than the device package affect it.
Since your use-case isn't likely to match the test setup it's not really of much use for design.
It's best use would be for comparing devices from different manufacturers, and as most don't list it for the 2N3055 (although some do) it's pretty much useless for that.
You can read more about it in this TI app note.

According to this Burr-Brown/TI app note the thermal resistance (junction to ambient) on a bare mounting configuration is variable but a reasonable upper limit is 30 C/W.

We can find a range of thermal resistances for TO-3 packages such as this steel one with 35°C/W, and even this one that specifies 39°C/W.
It's not specified how the part is mounted and connected, which will have significant effects. The case material will also have an effect.
If you have a serious need to know an accurate number, I suggest mocking it up with an actual sample from the intended manufacturer(s) and measuring it. The TO-3 package is pretty easy to measure.
Although the 2N3055 is specified for operation up to Tj=200°C, the characteristics won't be great and it likely won't be very reliable. A little bit of a heat sink, even copper on a PCB will make a big difference. Also, there are a lot of '2N3055's around that don't meet datasheet specs because they have a tiny die inside rather than the beefy original.

How would you go about measuring the TO-3 package & deriving its RθJA  ?
I have both steel & aluminum packages, about 80 pcs. From the 1980s.

Mount it in the exact way you intend to use it. Attach a small sensor to the package (I would use a stick-on ribbon thermocouple type T or K). Cause the transistor to dissipate power by connecting it to a bench supply with a resistor to the base. Allow the temperature to stabilize near where you intend to use it. Measure the input power minus the resistor dissipation and the temperature rise. Divide the two. As others have said, this is not a very useful number since it's unlikely one would use a 2N3055 without some kind of heat sink.

When you have a substantial heat sink (the normal situation) the more important number is the junction-to-case thermal resistance and the heat sink takes it from there (with a bit of additional thermal resistance between the case of the heat sink, depending on any thermal compound and any insulation you might insert).

Thank you Sperhro, I'll give it ago.
